# Cells postions change

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to solve the problem with data shown in table(see image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCvy3.png

What im trying to do is that 3 column text to be replaced by 6 column sum
                             and 4 column tex to be replaced by 6 column sum.

The code that im writing is this.What did i miss?

```
        $this->load->library('datatables');
        $this->datatables
            ->select("DATE_FORMAT({$this->db->dbprefix('payments')}.date, '%Y-%m-%d %T') as date, " . $this->db->dbprefix('payments') . ".reference_no as payment_ref, " . $this->db->dbprefix('sales') . ".reference_no as sale_ref, " . $this->db->dbprefix('purchases') . ".reference_no as purchase_ref, paid_by, amount, type, {$this->db->dbprefix('payments')}.id as id")
            ->from('payments')
            ->join('sales', 'payments.sale_id=sales.id', 'left')
            ->join('purchases', 'payments.purchase_id=purchases.id', 'left')
            ->group_by('payments.id');
```

Comment: What is javascript tag for?

Comment: Sorry for that!

Comment: OT: I really dislike objects that break up basic sql into unnecessary complexity and method calls.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I assumed that the complexity was necessary but simply beyond my comprehension

Comment: It only makes this less readable and more difficult from a code maintenance standpoint. Also, its purely personal opinion ;)

Comment: I know that is very complex thats why i need a bit help fro this

Comment: Never mind i fixed by my self